# How to attach multiple documents while sending mail from my Linked inbox

Tags: lumia-520

I am using Lumia 520.I have configured my gmail account to mobile's inbox. While sending mail from that inbox I couldn't find options to attach pdf or word documents.
  Please assist.

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do this now with Microsoft "Files" app if your mobile is upgraded to **WP 8.1**.
If you can not find it in your cellphone, install it from Microsoft App Store. And make sure you are installing **[Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e)** from **Microsoft Corporation** publisher. Here is the link to the app:

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e

- Open **Files** app
- locate your files
- Select multiple files (Screenshot 1 below)
- Press share button at the bottom (Screenshot 2 below)

You will find several options there to share your aap, like email, Bluetooth, OneNote, Facebook etc.

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Select multiple files and press share button below (last button at bottom)]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Multiple sharing options will appear here. Now choose Mail option]

Answer (score 1):

Sending attachments works the other way around - rather than going to your email, and creating the message, and attaching the documents; you do it the other way around. For example, if your documents are saved to your OneDrive, you can navigate to the folder with them, tap to the left of the file name(s) you want, and choose "**share**" (second from right in the bottom app bar, when you have a selection) and you can then send via email.

That said, if you only want to attach photos, you can do this from an email that you're composing, by tapping the **+** button

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the Gmail web version. Setup your Gmail properly using the Outlook app on your Lumia 535 by opening Outlook app then tapping the 3 little dots to bring up menu > then tap 'Add Email Account'. Fill in your Gmail details. You will then have a Google Mail icon in your list. Open this version of outlook app > press the + symbol to type new email. Finally hit the paperclip to attach your Gmail file.

Comment: Please read the question carfully before answering. He is not using the Gmail web version. He says *Linked Indbox* which is only present in the built-in outlook mail app.